# NEON Optimization for Splitting YUYV into Planes

Tags: c++, opengl, arm, neon, yuv

I want to learn how to use NEON to split YUYV into Y, U, and V planes to later feed the data as OpenGL textures to the GPU.

Currently, I am doing it in C++ like this:

```
/**
* TopOpenGL splitYuvPlanes()
* Purpose: splitYuvPlanes - Split YUYV into 3 arrays - one for each component
*
* @param data - input data
* @param size - input data size
* @param y - array to store output channels
* @param u - array to store output channels
* @param v - array to store output channels
*/
void TopOpenGL::splitYuvPlanes(unsigned char *data, int size, unsigned char *y, unsigned char *u, unsigned char *v)
{

    // This case takes RGBA -> BGRA
//    __asm__ volatile(
//                "mov r3, r3, lsr #3\n"           /* Divide number of pixels by 8 because we process them 8 at a time */
//                "loopRGBA:\n"
//                "vld4.8 {d0-d3}, [r1]!\n"        /* Load 8 pixels into d0 through d2. d0 = R[0-7], d1 = G[0-7], d2 = B[0-7], d3 = A[0-7] */
//                "subs r3, r3, #1\n"              /* Decrement the loop counter */
//                "vswp d0, d2\n"                  /* Swap R and B channels */
//                "vst4.8 {d0-d3}, [r2]!\n"        /* Store the RGBA into destination 8 pixels at a time */
//                "bgt loopRGBA\n"
//                "bx lr\n"
//                );

    for ( int c = 0 ; c < ( size - 4 ) ; c+=4 ) {

        *y = *data; // Y0
        data++;
        *u = *data; // U0
        u++;
        *u = *data; // U0
        data++;
        y++;
        *y = *data; // Y1
        data++;
        *v = *data; // V0
        v++;
        *v = *data; // V0

        data++;
        y++;
        u++;
        v++;
    }

}
```

How can I do this splitting into char *y, char *u, and char *v using NEON? Thank you.

I've found this blog, but it doesn't quite do what I want. 
http://blog.lumberlabs.com/2011/04/efficiently-splitting-cbcr-plane-with.html

Comment: `vld4.8` to 4 registers(`y0/2/4/6`, `u/0/2/4/6`, `y1/3/5/7`, `v0/2/4/6`);, `VZIP.8` `y0/2/4/6` and `y1/3/5/7` to `y0/1/2/3` and `y4/5/6/7`, then `vst` all

Comment: [This question on NEON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106500/neon-sse-and-interleaving-loads-vs-shuffles) was recently asked and has a link to an [ARM blog on NEON loads/stores](https://community.arm.com/groups/processors/blog/2010/03/17/coding-for-neon--part-1-load-and-stores) which explains `vld` and `vst` for stream muxing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code accomplishes the goal of splitting the YUYV frame into Y, U, and V planes.

```
/// This structure is passed to ARM Assembly code
/// to split the YUV frame into seperate planes for
/// OpenGL Consumption
typedef struct {
    uchar *input_data;
    uint32_t input_size;
    uchar *y_plane;
    uchar *u_plane;
    uchar *v_plane;
} yuvSplitStruct;

void TopOpenGL::splitYuvPlanes(yuvSplitStruct *yuvStruct)
{

    __asm__ volatile(

                "PUSH {r4}\n"                            /* Save callee-save registers R4 and R5 on the stack */
                "PUSH {r5}\n"                            /* r1 is the pointer to the input structure ( r0 is 'this' because c++ ) */
                "ldr r0 , [r1]\n"                        /* reuse r0 scratch register for the address of our frame input */
                "ldr r2 , [r1, #4]\n"                    /* use r2 scratch register to store the size in bytes of the YUYV frame */
                "ldr r3 , [r1, #8]\n"                    /* use r3 scratch register to store the destination Y plane address */
                "ldr r4 , [r1, #12]\n"                   /* use r4 register to store the destination U plane address */
                "ldr r5 , [r1, #16]\n"                   /* use r5 register to store the destination V plane address */
                    "mov r2, r2, lsr #5\n"               /* Divide number of bytes by 32 because we process 16 pixels at a time */
                    "loopYUYV:\n"
                        "vld4.8 {d0-d3}, [r0]!\n"        /* Load 8 YUYV elements from our frame into d0-d3, increment frame pointer */
                        "vst2.8 {d0,d2}, [r3]!\n"        /* Store both Y elements into destination y plane, increment plane pointer */
                        "vmov.F64 d0, d1\n"              /* Duplicate U value */
                        "vst2.8 {d0,d1}, [r4]!\n"        /* Store both U elements into destination u plane, increment plane pointer */
                        "vmov.F64 d1, d3\n"              /* Duplicate V value */
                        "vst2.8 {d1,d3}, [r5]!\n"        /* Store both V elements into destination v plane, increment plane pointer */
                        "subs r2, r2, #1\n"              /* Decrement the loop counter */
                    "bgt loopYUYV\n"                     /* Loop until entire frame is processed */
                "POP {r5}\n"                             /* Restore callee-save registers */
                "POP {r4}\n"
    );

}
```